# Build CocosSharp app using Xamarin Studio 6?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, cocossharp

For several months I've been building a game using CocosSharp on XS 5. With iOS 10 coming out, it looks like I'm going to have to upgrade to XS 6, but there's no support for CocosSharp.

How would one go about adding CocosSharp support to Xamarin Stuio 6?

I have tried finding info on this, and the two or three threads I've found that mention it's possible only say things like "You can work without the add-in, if you build from source, but that requires a bit more setup..." which doesn't give me any idea how to do that or what setup is required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an open source project, either you put your hope on some other guy to fix it, or you hack it and contribute, https://github.com/mono/CocosSharp/issues/362 Asking such on StackOverflow is useless.